# RegEx to strip BBCode tags from a string

Tags: c#, regex, bbcode, digest, markitup

I'm working on a feature that uses the JQuery MarkItUp! editor as a BBCode editor. I'm only allowing a small subset of BBCodes including the following:

```
[b]
[i]
[quote]
[quote=Mr Incredible]
[img]
[url]
[youtube]
```

I have a 1,500 character "Description" field that uses the editor, but I'm also planning to store a 150 character *digest* of the description with all of the BBCode stripped out.

I'm currently using a simple RegEx to do this in C#.  It basically nukes embedded BBCodes in a string, but it leaves behind a lot of "noisy content" like the [img] URL or the [youtube] video ID that I'd also like to remove from the digest.

Here's my current RegEx:

```
  public static String StripBBCode(string bbCode)
  {
     string r = Regex.Replace(bbCode,
     @"\[(.*?)\]",
     String.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

     // Finally, replace all newlines with a space
     r = Regex.Replace(r,
     @"(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)+",
     @" ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

     return r;
  }
```

If I run the following string through this function, I get the result shown below:

**source**

```
This is [b]bold[/b]. This is [i]italic[/i].

Here is an image:
[img]http://www.phatmac.com/Pics/Movies/Incredibles.jpg[/img]

Here is a link to [url=http://espn.go.com]ESPN[/url].

Here is a YouTube video:

[youtube]WJ0UkZ3W4FA[/youtube]
```

**result**

This is bold. This is italic. Here is an image: http://www.phatmac.com/Pics/Movies/Incredibles.jpg Here is a link to ESPN. Here is a YouTube video: WJ0UkZ3W4FA

**Here's what I want to get back**

This is bold. This is italic. Here is an image: Here is a link to ESPN. Here is a YouTube video:

How can I modify my StripBBCode() function to achieve this?

***EDITED***

The suggestion from David below in the first answer was correct.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
 string r = Regex.Replace(s,
    @"\[youtube\].*\[\/youtube\]",
    String.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 r = Regex.Replace(r,
    @"\[img\].*\[\/img\]",
    String.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several tags that you want the content removed, and the rest where you only want the tags removed.

Do replace of `[img].*[/img]` with string.empty, and `[youtube].*[/youtube]`, and whatever else you need the contents removed, then do your removal of `[.*]`.

Edit:

I'm not a regex expert either, but I think `@"\[img\].*?\[/img\]"` is what you want. I don't think you need the parentheses in `@"\[(.*?)\]"`, I think in this context parentheses means to save the matched text so you can match it again with `\1`.

Comment: What does the RegEx for removing [img].*[/img] look like? I'm no RegEx maven, and the original regular expressions in my function were the result of many cut-and-paste sessions to get the syntax right.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a version added to the end of the original question that seems to work.  Mine doesn't have the embedded question mark as yours does.  Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I appreciate it!

Comment: The question mark on `.*?` makes that expression lazy, consuming the minimum number of characters necessary to satisfy the expression. Without it, the regular expression will reduce `[img]asdf[/img] Important Text [img]asdf[/img]` to an empty string.